# Error deleting a join table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a join table named `favorites`. It doesn't have a single auto incrementing id. It uses both `user_id` and `doctor_id`.

My issue is when trying to delete this record. On Rails 5.0 and 5.1 it throws the following error.

```
favorite = Favorite.first
=> #<Favorite:0x007fe8b1546bf8 user_id: 3, doctor_id: 2, created_at: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 03:37:10 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 03:37:10 UTC +00:00>
favorite.delete
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I supposed to be deleting this record some other way or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known rails issue. You can find out more detail [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13893).

You have to add primary key in intermediate table check [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20755)

Comment: `You have to add primary key in intermediate table` I have this content in my answer. If you read carefully. This provide answer as well. By adding primary key in intermediate table this error gone. This statement also contain main context of link I provided in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My initial search through the Rails issues didn't find those. 